# mutate_each in dplyr not working column-wise over dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

In this case, I'm attempting to apply the `quantile` function to this example dataframe:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(9, 1, 10),ncol=3,nrow=3))

DF_of_quantiles <- DF %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(quantile(DF,c(0.98), na.rm=TRUE)))
```

But `mutate_each` does not perform the function over the columns:

`View(DF_of_quantiles)`

gives

```
    V1  V2  V3
1   9.822732    9.822732    9.822732
2   9.822732    9.822732    9.822732
3   9.822732    9.822732    9.822732
```

Notice that

`View(quantile(DF,c(0.98), na.rm=TRUE)`

gives the same value:

```
    row.names   x
1   98% 9.822732
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When using `dplyr::funs()`, don't forget you need to use  `.` as a dummy parameter in the argument you wish to pass the data into, meaning that it would be written

```
quantile(., 0.98, na.rm = TRUE)
```

inside `funs`.  Additionally, for this operation I think you may prefer `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
summarise_each(DF, funs(quantile(., 0.98, na.rm=TRUE)))
#         V1       V2       V3
# 1 4.868255 6.937773 7.864751
```

If you pass `DF` to `quantile` through `funs`, you'll receive a result that is the same as calling `quantile` on the entire data frame:

```
summarise_each(DF, funs(quantile(DF, 0.98, na.rm=TRUE)))
#         V1       V2       V3
# 1 7.830681 7.830681 7.830681
quantile(as.matrix(DF), 0.98, names = FALSE)
# [1] 7.830681
```

Which is what you are seeing as a result of your `mutate_each` call, but is not what you want.  Also, `mutate_each` with `.` will give correct but undesirable results

```
mutate_each(DF, funs(quantile(., 0.98, na.rm=TRUE)))
#         V1       V2       V3
# 1 4.868255 6.937773 7.864751
# 2 4.868255 6.937773 7.864751
# 3 4.868255 6.937773 7.864751
```

Check:

```
vapply(DF, quantile, 1, 0.98)
#       V1       V2       V3 
# 4.868255 6.937773 7.864751
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone came across this question and is OK with a build-in function [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html).

```
# 2 mean column wise, 1 means row wise
> apply(DF, 2, function(x)quantile(x, 0.5))
      V1       V2       V3 
5.953192 8.144576 3.528949
```

---

Thanks to thelatemail's suggestion, I added the output of [lapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html), sapply and the output.

```
> lapply(DF, function(x)quantile(x, 0.5))
$V1
50% 
5.953192 

$V2
50% 
8.144576 

$V3
50% 
3.528949 

> sapply(DF, function(x)quantile(x, 0.5))
V1.50%   V2.50%   V3.50% 
5.953192 8.144576 3.528949
```

Comment: I think using `lapply` or `sapply` is preferable when acting on data.frame columns. No need to specify the dimension then.

Comment: You also don't necessarily need the `function(x) ...` part - `lapply(DF, quantile, probs=0.5)` will work for example.